# How can I add additional source folders into NetBeans with Maven projects?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I use `build-helper-maven-plugin` for adding additional sources with Maven profiles and it's just fine.

The problem is NetBeans doesn't recognises my additional folder(e.g. `${project.basedir}/src/main/java-some`) and the editor doesn't work for those files as Java.

Is there any to to solve this problem?

Comment: `1. right click on project
2. choose "Properties"
3. choose "Sources" (top left in the tree)
4. choose "Source Package Folders:" (left side)
5. choose "Add Folder". `is this what you want or did i understand it wrong?

Comment: @Apostolos I'm afraid your instructions are for native NetBeans projects. I wondering with Maven projects.

Comment: why just adding the extra folders would be a problem even for a maven project? that's what i do in eclipse and in jidea too. i manually specify the extra source folders in order to develop in IDE and when it comes to building, maven does what it needs to do.